# Play Pokemon GO on Root with joystick on Systemless Root

Tags: geolocation, pokemon-go, systemless-root

I have Samsung A5 with android 5.1.1 systemless rooted. I want to play pokemon go. But enabling Mock Locations disable the game. I tried an Xposed module to hide this, then the joystick app also can't detect it.So it won't work. I am also unable to find the pokemon go module from Xposed. Is there any way to play it on root with joystick?? I know it is a violation of rules, but I do not have much option.

Comment: No, there isn't... You can try Magisk Hide and it will pass SafetyNet API checks, but when Magisk is hidden you can't hide Mock Locations. Pokemon Go is actively enforcing the rules and app updates are constantly be released with more and more detection of rules violations. "I know it is a violation of rules, but I do not have much option," you will have problems getting people here to assist too much with a blatant violation of terms of service, the best you will likely get is vague pointers like I gave you. (I don't even play Pokemon Go, left it because they actively block rooted devices)